# Decompressing .sit file

Tags: terminal

I have recently downloaded a `.sit` archive file.

Is there a way to decompress it at the command line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### [The Unarchiver](http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver.html)

Includes a commandline tool. Can unpack some SIT files. I think I have experienced problems with a few SIT files though.

Comment: The Unarchiver provides the tool `unar`, that you have to download separately and install yourself.

Comment: Yep - appears to work well on sit files, and has been recently updated (July 2010).

Answer (score 3):

I’m sure that [Stuffit Deluxe](http://www.stuffit.com/mac-home.html) has two command line utilities called *stuff* and *unstuff* (they're in `/usr/local/bin`) as far as I can remember. But you need the Deluxe payware version.

If paying is not your idea, you could technically do the same using the free [Stuffit Expander](http://www.stuffit.com/mac-expander.html). You have to invoke it from the Terminal with something like:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "StuffIt Expander" to expand posix file “/path/to/full/file/compressedfile.sit”’
```

It might not be the best, but it should work.

Comment: +1, good answer. You should also be able to do `open -a /Applications/Stuffit\ Expander.app /path/to/the/file.sit`

Comment: The last time I tried the official StuffIt it was spectacular bloatware. I'd avoid it if at all possible.